# What does 'by right belongs' mean in this context?

Tags: hadith, terminology

I was reading a Islamic tradition which says "Therefore, whatever I decide for anyone which **by right belongs** to his brother, he must not take anything, for I am granting him only a portion of Hell."

From my understanding, it seems to indicate it means, if he decides for someone and the judgement is wrong, the person who won the judgement shouldn't take the judgement and tell the truth. Am I correct?

The full context:

> Muhammad said: "I am only a human being, and you bring your disputes to me,
>   some perhaps being more eloquent in their plea than others, so that I give
>   judgement on their behalf according to what I hear from them.
>   Therefore, whatever I decide for anyone which by right belongs to his
>   brother, he must not take anything, **for** I am granting him only a
>   portion of Hell.

Comment: *By right* means *lawfully*. *For*, in this case, means *since* (or *because*).

Comment: @Mick Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dividing the sentence up wrongly. With additional punctuation

> Whatever I decide for anyone which, by right, belongs to his brother ....

The "By right" means "properly" or "justly". "Deciding for someone" means for a judge to agree with one side of an argument. The meaning of the full example seems clear: Judges may be fallible. If you know you are in the wrong then don't try to benefit from a judge's decision. To do so is a sin.